# Slim 3 - how add or-option into the route?

Tags: routes, slim, slim-3

How can I have or-option in the [Slim 3 routes](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html)?

For instance, this is what I do currently:

```
// Home page.
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Get the application settings.
    $settings = $this->get('settings');

    // Check if the home page class is provided.
    ... lots of codes
});

$app->get('/home', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // Get the application settings.
    $settings = $this->get('settings');

    // Check if the home page class is provided.
    ... lots of codes
});
```

instead of repeating the chunks of these codes, can I make them into one like:

```
$app->get('/ or /home', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
...}
```

Comment: Isn't [optional segments](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#optional-segments) is what you want?

Comment: yes it is! thank you!

Comment: @EvgenySoynov add your comment as an answer, please. Then the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optional segments](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#optional-segments) is what you're looking for.